# Are they talking about virtual memory in this article?

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory, paging

I am reading this Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation

And I am in this paragraph:

> **Segmentation with paging**
>
> Instead of a memory location, the segment information includes the
> address of a page table for the segment. When a program references a
> memory location the offset is translated to a memory address using the
> page table. A segment can be extended by allocating another memory
> page and adding it to the segment's page table.
>
> An implementation of virtual memory on a system using segmentation
> with paging usually only moves individual pages back and forth between
> main memory and secondary storage, similar to a paged non-segmented
> system. Pages of the segment can be located anywhere in main memory
> and need not be contiguous. This usually results in a reduced amount
> of input/output between primary and secondary storage and reduced
> memory fragmentation.

In the second paragraph they are clearly talking about virtual memory. But are they also talking about virtual memory in the first paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the first paragraph is also talking about virtual memory concepts. It describes how to translate virtual addresses (used by programs) into physical addresses in the main memory. The page table holds the mappings between virtual pages and physical page frames. When a program references a virtual address, the page table is used to determine which physical page frame that virtual address is mapped to, and the offset within that page frame.